# Is there a way to redirect all Telegram messages received by an account to a Telegram group, channel or bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram-api

I am trying to take all received messages from my telegram account (which i use for customer support, and is already known and used by my customers) and forward them to a subscription list (the support team). I built a Java Telegram bot that will accept subscriptors, keep an updated subscriptors list and forward all messages it receives to all subscriptors (besides doing some message processing). But I am stuck at the last step:

**I need a specific Telegram account that already exists to take all new received messages and forward them to my bot**, so it can handle the rest. But I couldn't find a way to do so in the Telegram API documentation.

I am also relatively new to programming (<2years experience) so dumbed down replies are greatly appreciated.

I read all the documentation i could find, but it all relates to forwarding messages from groups and channels. I need to forward messages from all individual communications to my acount, i.e. private chats. I have been spending many hours on this subject and am starting to feel maybe it can't be done.